# Head-internal relative clauses

Tags: nuances, parsing, relative-clauses

I am trying to figure out head-internal relative clauses. A paper I looked at presented two versions of the same sentence, one with the head word (りんご) outside the relative clause:

> [皿の上にあった]**りんご**をくすねた。

And one version where it is inside the relative clause:

> [**りんご**が皿の上にあった]のをくすねた。

Do these two sentences mean exactly the same thing, or are there differences in nuance? When are head-internal relative clauses usually used in Japanese?

Answer (score 4):

They are slightly different, if not much. The former sounds saying a fact relatively objectively.

On the other hand, the latter rather means "although an apple was on the plate, s/he stole it" and it sounds somehow accusive in the sense that it should have been there. In grammar for old Japanese, a similar form is considered a conjunction.

> When are head-internal relative clauses usually used in Japanese?

I forgot to answer to this part. Speaking of this usage of を, not specifically to "head-internal relative clause", I personally use it like a weaker version of のに in the point of paradoxical sense, mostly in the form of "…、それをさぁ～、…。". So, I think I've been using it to some degree. I personally am used to the form of HIRC with を too. But I'm not sure other native speakers share that sense.

Comment: I personally don't feel the sentence with the head-internal relative clause is more disapprobative than the other. It would seem mistaken at least to ascribe an adversative sense to the HIRC, given it can be used in sentences like「財布を落としたのを拾ってあげた」「困っているのを助けてあげた」 unproblematically.

Comment: @goldbrick Good point. It's only a result of answering to the specific example. There's the same problem when we call 「名前を呼ばれた」"adversative passive".

Answer (score -1):

I could have the wrong end of the stick here, but your second example doesn't make sense to me.

#### Part 1: regular relative clause

Let's look at your first example first.

> [皿の上にあった]**りんご**をくすねた。

At its core (haha, pun not intended), we have:

> **りんご**をくすねた。
>     I pilfered the **apple**.

The relative clause portion tells us more about the apple:

> [皿の上にあった]
>     [(it) was on the plate]

Looking at the whole utterance, we get:

> [皿の上にあった]**りんご**をくすねた。
>     I pilfered the **apple** [(that) was on the plate].

#### Part 2: nominalized clause

Now let's look at your second example.

> [**りんご**が皿の上にあった]のをくすねた。

The core here is more complicated, because we don't have a simple concrete noun as the object of our verb くすねた.  Instead, we have the の, which here is used to nominalize (make a noun out of) the entire preceding clause.

So let's look at the embedded clause.

> [**りんご**が皿の上にあった]
>     [The **apple** was on the plate]

Okay, simple enough.

After this, though, we have that の, turning our entire embedded clause into a nominalized phrase.  This can be a bit messy to translate into English; it comes through somewhat similar to "the fact that", or "the act of", or sometimes by turning a verb into the "-ing" form.  Some examples:

> ラーメンを食べるのが好きです。
>     I like (the act of) eating ramen.

Note that this is different from just *"I like ramen"*.  We're not talking about "ramen" as the main noun, but rather about the whole clause that contains "ramen" -- in this case, about "eating" it.

> 道子さんが東京に行ったのは知らなかった。
>     I didn't know (the fact) that Michiko went to Tokyo.

Again, this is different from *"I didn't know Michiko"*.  We're not talking about "Michiko" as the main noun, but rather about the whole clause that contains "Michiko" -- in this case, that she "went to Tokyo".

Looking again at the whole second example sentence then:

> [**りんご**が皿の上にあった]のをくすねた。

The key is that it turns the *whole* embedded clause into a kind of noun: we're not talking about "the apple" anymore, but rather the fact that "the apple was on the plate".

Because of the verb here, くすねた / "pilfered", nothing quite makes sense -- just due to the meaning of the words, this doesn't fit together.  The best translation I can come up with would be something like:

> I pilfered (the fact that) [the **apple** was on the plate].

...???  That doesn't make sense in English.  Nor does the Japanese make sense.  (At least, as I understand it.)

If you change the verb from くすねた to 見た, that would work:

> [**りんご**が皿の上にあった]のを**見た**。
>     I **saw** (the fact) that [the **apple** was on the plate].

---

The paper in question appears to be this one:

- [**日本語主要部内在型関係節の時制解釈**](http://www.ls-japan.org/modules/documents/LSJpapers/journals/143_nomura.pdf), by 野村 益寛 of 北海道大学, published in 2013 in volume 143 of **言語研究**.

This seems to have been written by a native speaker of Japanese, which makes that second sample sentence a bit of a head-scratcher for me.

For the verb くすねる, I'm only aware of the sense *"pilfer, filch, sneak, pinch, swipe"*, with the core underlying meaning of *"to steal something sneakily"*.  There might be a sense of くすねる that I'm missing, which could make the second sample sentence work better.

Comment: The second sentence is fine like user4092 says in their answer.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, I'm passingly familiar with the 古文 usage (similar to modern のに), but I'm unfamiliar with that usage in the modern language.  How does it parse?

Comment: HIRCs (sometimes IHRCs) have been discussed quite often in the literature – see e.g. *The mechanism of inverted relativization in Japanese: A silent linker and inversion* (Hiraiwa 2012) – but their grammatical status is somewhat controversial.  Educated native speakers use them, even in professional writing, but not everyone is happy with the way they sound.  If you ask for acceptability judgments, [native speakers sometimes rate them poorly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25211952#25211952).

Comment: @snailboat, is the のを here similar in function to the 古文 variety, parsing out as similar to のに?  If so, I'd argue that this isn't a relative clause at all...

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Consider the examples from the first page of this paper, perhaps: http://www.lingref.com/cpp/wccfl/31/paper3018.pdf